# How to interpret a significant multiple regression model without significant predictors?

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I am struggling with interpreting the result of a multiple regression model of my study. The regression model was significant in *F-statistics*, but any predictor was not significant in *t-value* as you can see below:

```
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.05852 -0.01197 -0.00183  0.01205  0.06099 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)     0.0916     0.0788    1.16    0.279  
HipLoadingK     0.5788     0.3048    1.90    0.094 .
HipAbsK         1.3069     1.1073    1.18    0.272  
KneeLoadingK    0.2029     1.4192    0.14    0.890  
KneeAbsK       -1.0270     1.1105   -0.92    0.382  
AnkleLoadingK   0.3377     0.7853    0.43    0.679  
AnkleAbsK       0.9472     0.9536    0.99    0.350  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0411 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.803, Adjusted R-squared:  0.656 
F-statistic: 5.45 on 6 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.0159
```

In this case, how do I interpret the result?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be fitting a model with 7 parameters with only 15 observations, which is ridiculous in almost all cases.

Descriptively, this amounts to a massive overfit.

Regarding hypothesis tests, because of the small sample, you will fully rely on all assumptions of the normal linear model to be fulfilled, like

- uncorrelated errors,
- equal variance,
- normality of the errors,
- correct model specification.

If these are perfectly fulfilled, you could draw the usual conclusion:

"At the 5% level, the covariables show some effect on the average response. None of their effects is significant at the 5% level."

Comment: Good points (+1) but why do you say **3** variables ? It seems to me that there are 6

Comment: @RobertLong: I was counting "Hip", "Knee", "Ankle" (each with multiple factor levels), but I think your guess is better ;).

Comment: ....guess being the operative word :D